# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code, a line is producing this error in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

It was working perfectly fine before and just decided to stop. The code on the line it mentions is:

```
$('#next').click(){
    $('#atestimonial').load('http://website.com/testimonialPull.php');
    return false;
  });
```

I cant see whats wrong with that, the thing its loading exists I have checked and it generates the text needed, so its a problem with the load / .click()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to pass a function to the `click` function, but not doing it correctly. Instead try something like this:

```
$('#next').click(
   function(){
      $('#atestimonial').load('http://website.com/testimonialPull.php');
      return false;
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('#next').click(){ //<<<
    $('#atestimonial').load('http://website.com/testimonialPull.php');
    return false;
  });
```

Remove the `)`:

```
  $('#next').click(function(){
    $('#atestimonial').load('http://website.com/testimonialPull.php');
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the answer! Fixed that issue, now its giving me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( [which is the line below]

Comment: Write out as `$('#next').click(function() { // function here });` so the fact that you are defining a function handler for the onclick event is very clear, that would help avoid issues like this one.

Comment: @DavidHedlund ha forgot about that